# Best straight-line approximation for $\sin(2x)$ on $(-\pi,\pi)$

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

I'm working on the second part of this problem from Strang's Linear Algebra, 4e (problem 3.4.21):

> What is the closest function $a\cos(x) + b\sin(x)$ to the function $f(x) = \sin(2x)$ on the interval from $-\pi$ to $\pi$? What is the closest straight line $c + dx$?

The solution says,

> By orthogonality, the closest functions are $0\sin(2x) = 0$ and $0 + 0x = 0$.

That is, $a=b=c=d=0$.

However, it seems that $d$ should not be zero, as $x$ is not orthogonal to $\sin(2x)$ on the interval given:

$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}x\sin(2x) dx = -\pi$

Here is how I solved it (by least squares). We have

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
c \\
d \\
\end{bmatrix} = 
\sin(2x)
$$
Then the normal equations are

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} dx & \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}x dx \\
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}x dx & \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}x^2 dx \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
c \\
d \\
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin(2x) dx \\
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}x\sin(2x) dx  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2\pi & 0 \\
0 & \frac{2}{3}\pi^3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
c \\
d \\
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
-\pi \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which yields
$$
c= 0, d= \frac{-3}{2\pi^2} \\
y= \frac{-3}{2\pi^2}x
$$

I think I'm right, because my solution has lower error than $y=0$:
$$
E_1^2 = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (\sin(2x) - 0)^2 dx = \pi \\
E_2^2 = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (\sin(2x) + \frac{3}{2\pi^2}x)^2 dx = 2.664
$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Since $x \mapsto \sin 2 x$ is odd, so is the best straight-line approximation $s(x) = c + d x$---by symmetry if $s(x)$ is a best approximation, so is $-s(-x)$, and by uniqueness $s(x) = -s(-x)$. Thus, $c = 0$, simplifying the remaining computation. (The same argument applies to any class of functions closed under the involution $s(x) \mapsto -s(-x)$.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to find out is to minimize the following integral directly with respect to $a$,

$$I(a)= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} [\sin(2x) -ax]^2 dx = \frac{\pi}{3}(2\pi^2a^2+6a+3)
$$

Setting $I’(a) =0$ produces the same result as the least square method, i.e. $a=-3/(2\pi^2)$. Then,

$$I = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left[ \sin(2x) + \frac{3x}{2\pi^2}\right]^2 dx = \pi - \frac{3}{2\pi} < \pi
$$

Thus, $f(x)=0x+0$ is not the best fit.

——————

Edit: Keep in mind, though, the book may be using a different criteria for the optimal solution. For instance, it may assume that the best fit is for functions to have the same average value. In this case, $f(x)=0x$ would be the answer, because

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin(2x) dx = 0
$$

Comment: Would you mind double-checking your error calculation for me? When I plug that integral into my calculator, I get 2.664. If the true error is greater than pi, then my answer is indeed incorrect, but then I don't understand why solving the normal equations doesn't find the *absolute* minimum solution (since the way you derive the normal equations is by minimizing $I$ as you've given it).

Comment: Sorry, I double checked. It’s indeed 2.66. You are still right